# open pdf file with sessionAsSigner

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a database where the user doesn't has access to.
Still I can go to the database and "read" the documents with for example

`var db:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase("","somedir/some.nsf");`

In this database there's a pdf file I would like to open or download. I have the filename and the unid . If the user had acces to the database I could do it with

```
http(s)://[yourserver]/[application.nsf] /xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/ [application.nsf]/[UNID|/$File/[AttachmentName]?Open
```

How can I do it with sessionAsSigner without putting a $PublicAccess=1 field on the form ?

**edit:**
the pdf file is stored as **attachment in a richtextfield**

**second edit**

I'm trying to use the XSnippet from Naveen and made some changes

The error message I get is :  'OutStream' not found

The code I tried is :

```
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + zipFileName);

var embeddedObj:NotesEmbeddedObject = null;
var bufferInStream:java.io.BufferedInputStream = null;
var outStream:java.io.OutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

embeddedObj = downloadDocument.getAttachment(fileName);
  if (embeddedObj != null) {
    bufferInStream = new     java.io.BufferedInputStream(embeddedObj.getInputStream());
    var bufferLength = bufferInStream.available();
    var data = new byte[bufferLength];
    bufferInStream.read(data, 0, bufferLength); // Read the attachment data
```

**ON THE NEXT LINE IS THE PROBLEM**

```
OutStream.write(data); // Write attachment into pdf

bufferInStream.close();
embeddedObj.recycle();
  }


downloadDocument.recycle();

outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Comment: Change your line to `outStream.write(data); ` - var outStream doesn't start with a capital letter.

Comment: Yes your right. It's working now. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an XAgent (= XPage without rendering) which takes datebase + documentid + filename as URL parameters and delivers the file as response OutputStream.

The URL would be

```
http(s)://[yourserver]/download.nsf/download.xsp?db=[application.nsf]&unid=[UNID]&attname=[AttachmentName]
```

for an XAgent download.xsp in a database download.nsf.

The code behind the XAgent runs as sessionAsSigner and is able to read the file even the user itself has no right to access file's database.

Use [Eric's blog](https://edm00se.io/xpages/custom-JSON-with-Java-sized-XAgent/) (+ [Java code](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=example-json-data-provider-using-gson-and-an-xagent)) as a starting point. Replace "application/json" with "application/pdf" and stream pdf file instead of json data.

As an alternative you can adapt this [XSnippet code from Thomas Adrian](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=display-and-download-any-files-from-the-server-file-system-or-from-a-mapped-drive). Use `download()` together with `grabFile()` to write your pdf-File to OutputStream.

Instead of extracting attachment file to path and reading it from there you can stream the attachment right from document to response's OutputStream. Here is an [XSnippet from Naveen Maurya](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=download-all-attachments) as a good example.

Comment: I see how I can convert data to json in this blog , but I don't understand how to change the code in order to stream the pdf file and to run it as sessionAsSigner. Could you help me with that ?

Comment: I added some Java code links to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: the code from Naveen works fine. Any idea how to change the code to save it to pdf instead to zip ? I'll have to change this line to response.setContentType("application/pdf"); but what do I have to change in the "lLoop through all the attachments" in order to get the pdf instead of a zip file ?

Comment: As you know the name of your pdf-File already you wouldn't loop but get it with `embeddedObj = downloadDocument.getAttachment("yourPdfFile.pdf");` instead

Comment: ok, I changed that in the XSnippet . How do I have to change the code to get the pdf directly without zipping ? (I don't know java ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the PDF file as a stream, you should be able to use the OutputStream of the external context's response.

Stephan Wissel has a blog posting about writing out an ODF file so you should be able to cut that up as a starting point.

http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8248MT

You already have the db so, you will just need to know the UNID of the document.

```
var doc = db.getDocumentByUNID(unid) 'unid is a supplied param
var itm:RichTextItem = doc.getFirstItem("Body") 'assuming file is in body field
```

Once you have the itm, you can loop round all of the embeddedObjects and get the pdf file. At this point, I don't know if you can stream it directly or if you have to detach it, but assuming you detach it, you will then use something like this.

```
 File file = new File("path to file");
 FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Don't forget to clean up the temporarily detached file

Comment: The problem remains the same I think. In this case the question would be "How to get a handle to the pdf file as a stream ? " I think ,correct me when I'm wrong,  this blog is more about rendering out or saving to another format. My question is more : How to get the pdf file

Comment: EmbeddedObject has a method getAsStream(). You use that to get the inputstream and then either Guava or Apache commons to copy that into the response.getOutputstream

Comment: Could you help me changing the Xsnippet in order to get the pdf instead of a pdf in a zip file ?